# Проблемы при установке Apache 2.4.2 и PHP 5.4.3 TS на Windows 7

Tags: веб-сервер, httpd, windows-7, php, apache2

Такое дело. Пытаюсь установить на локальном компе (с Windows 7 Ultimate x86) связку [Apache 2.4.2](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/) и [PHP 5.4.3-VC9-x86-Thread-Safe](http://windows.php.net/download/). PHP распакована в `C:\Prog\php`, apache - в `С:\Prog\Apache24`.

[Оттуда же](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/) скачиваю модуль для подключения php как модуля апача `php5apache2_4.dll-php-5.4-win32.zip`, распаковываю в `C:\Prog\php` и, как сказано, в ReadMe.txt приложенному к архиву, добавляю директивы в файл `C:\Prog\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf`.

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/Prog/php/php5apache2_4.dll"AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .phpPHPIniDir "C:/Prog/php"
```

+ некоторые настройки php.ini, httpd.conf и httpd-vhosts.conf. Затем запускаю

```
httpd.exe -k install
```

На что он мне отвечает следующим:

> `Installing the Apache2.4 serviceThe Apache2.4 service is successfully installed.Testing httpd.conf....Errors reported here must be corrected before the service can be started.httpd.exe: Syntax errors on line 172 of C: Prog/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Connot load C:/Prog/php/php5apache2_4.dll into server: The specifed module could not be found.`

Добрые люди в интернетах написали, что нужно проверить права на доступ пользователя, от имени которого работет апач, сменил ему пользователя на своего:

```
User Administrator   Group Administrators
```

не помогло.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что еще сделать. Если права поднастроить, то как, потому что я что-то терясюь в семерке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень трудно признавать свои ошибки, особенно такие глупые, но, подругому никак нельзя, вся проблема была в том, что, по невнимательности, я пытался запустить апач с версией PHP 5.4 **Non** Thread Safe, полагая, что это Thread Safe. Однако, в файле для модуля под апач ясно сказано "Runs with PHP 5.4 Thread Safe (TS)", не повторяйте моей ошибки.

Итог, берем [php-5.4.3-Win32-VC9-x86.zip](URL), 
смешиваем с [httpd-2.4.2-win32.zip](URL)
к php добавляем [php5apache2_4.dll-php-5.4-win32.zip](URL), * причем, в данном случае, важно взять именно файл из папки PHP 5.4.3 архива php5apache2_4.dll-php-5.4-win32.zip

вносим изменения в файл httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll" #вместо c:/php/ ваш вариантAddHandler application/x-httpd-php .phpPHPIniDir "C:/php" #вместо C:/php ваш вариант
```

и все замечательно работает.
Остальное по вкусу.

Answer (score 0):

Перенесите этот модуль в директорий, заданный в php.ini переменной extension_dir.

[Совет найден здесь](http://lifeofageekadmin.com/how-install-apache-2-4-php-5-4-and-mysql-5-5-21-on-windows-7/)

Comment: нет, не помогло, да и в ReadMe.txt, приложенному к модулю, сказано, что модуль нужно скопировать именно в корневую директорию php.Но проблему решил, ответ в комментарии к вопросу.